# Angular 2 - Grandchild Access

Tags: angular

How can I access a grandchild component? 
For example, I have a **grandparent.component.ts**, **parent.component.ts**, and **child.component.ts**. The **child.component.ts** has a list of buttons in its template. **The parent.component.ts** contains the **child.component.ts**. The **grandparent.component.ts** contains the **parent.component.ts**. I want to disable the buttons in the child.component.ts in the **grandparent.component.ts**. How do I do this?

Comment: Here is the plkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/8LqSzJT73AkSpYjpTVKv?p=catalogue

Comment: If BeetleJuice's answer is not feasible for you, and if you want to interact directly to the `ChildComponent` not by passing to the `ParentComponent` first then I can't think of other way than to access it via ElementRef and change the attribute manually. This is a very rough solution though.
https://plnkr.co/edit/CfspDAbXHhSi7COsO9Lt?p=preview

Comment: BTW, can't you do it by going in `ParentComponent` first? Like an event from `GrandParentComponent` then `ParentComponent` receives it then finally pass it to `ChildComponent`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would do this with a service. The service would:

- expose an observable that emits when controls should be disabled/enabled
- expose a function that should be called to make the observable emit

The order of events, for grandparent to disable grandchild's controls would be:

- grandchild subscribes to observable `onInit`
- grandparent calls the function
- function causes observable to emit
- grandchild receives the emission, and disables/enables its controls

In asnwer to your comment, here are two alternatives that **I would not recommend**

1. You could use `@Input()` in parent component and data binding in the grandparent template to pass a value from grandparent to parent, and use the same mechanism -- `@Input()` in child and databinding in parent template -- to pass the parent's databound property to the child.
2. grandparent could write a value to the `window` object since all components can see it. eg: `window.enableControls = false`. Child could have a `setInterval` or `Observable.interval` that reads that value every 500 milliseconds and updates child controls. Clear the interval when [the child component is destroyed](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/OnDestroy-class.html) or you'll have a memory leak.

Again, I would not recommend either option, but they would work.

Comment: Is there an alternative that would make you access the button of the grandchild itself?

Comment: @xiotee I've added a section to my answer.

Comment: Alternative number 1 is not ideal, but at least respectable to some point. Writing things to a global window variable, though...